# Upload file in drupal 7 in entityFormSubmit

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have created an entitity form and after form submit I am storing the data in database. But in case of file its not uploading the file and storing the file id in my database . I am new in creating Entityform so any help regarding this would be appritiable .

Also if I have done any wrong please let me know here is the code snippet .

## This is the file type  field

```
$entity_form['fields']['file_id'] = array(
                '#type' => 'file',
                '#title' => t('File'),
                '#title_display' => 'visible',
                '#size' => 128,
                '#theme_wrappers' => array(),

        );
```

## This is entityFormSubmit

```
 public function entityFormSubmit(&$entity_form, &$form_state) {
    $child_form_state = form_state_defaults();
    $form_state['storage']['#parent'] = $entity_form['#parents'];
    $child_form_state['values'] = drupal_array_get_nested_value($form_state['values'], $entity_form['#parents']);
    foreach ($child_form_state['values']['fields'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($key != 'options') {
            $entity_form['#entity']->$key = $value;
        } elseif($key == 'options') {
            $entity_form['#entity']->$key = serialize($value);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use the `managed_file` field type...

It's pretty simple and you can find an usage example at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file

Don't forget calling the `file_usage_add` function in your submit handler.